# How to capture data displayed on a pop up window

Tags: java, javascript, html, popup

I have a web application where the user selects some options on the web page and clicks 'submit' button. On clicking the submit button, the app queries a DB and displays the results in a **pop-up window**. Now, I have a strange requirement to capture the data that is displayed in the pop up window and save it in another DB. My question here is, how to get hold of the data that is displayed in the pop-up window. I am very new to this kind of stuff and im clueless about how to proceed.

Ill explain the above scenario with the help of an example.

Lets say, the user enters his name in the webpage and clicks submit. On submit, the DB is queried and the age of that particular person is displayed in the pop up. Now, I have to capture the value of age and save it another DB.

Comment: "pop-up window" means little, it could be a modal popup or a div displayed on top of the page, you need to provide more details. In any case, you cannot easily "read" from the popup, you should find where it's created (and its text is set).

Comment: how can DB display a msg on a popup window?? Don't you think you application is doing it??

Comment: @viruzzo: Its a modal pop-up.
Sunil: I did not understand what u are saying exactly. The DB is not displaying a msg in a pop up here. A web page queries a DB on clicking submit button and the result that is fetched from DB is displayed in a pop up window. I need to catch hold of the data that is being displayed in the pop up window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the DB returns the value for the first query (age in your case), instead of displaying the data, first store the value in some variable. Now, fire another query for storing the fetched data (age). After the second query is completed i.e. the age is saved in the DB, you can display the age as you are doing it right now.

Hope this helps !!!

Answer (score 1):

The open method in javascript for creating a pop-up window returns the object for accessing the DOM of that popup window. You can use this object to access to contents of the pop-up window.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will go through this and try to implement it. If i can get hold of the DOM, then its perfect.